# datatable jquery plugin: populate select to filter data acquired through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using the powerful jQuery plugin dataTable and I need to:
1. Get data from ajax source
2. Add select to filter output

that's the HTML code:

```
<table id='probecardlist' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Selection</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Production Area</th>
        <th>Format</th>
        <th>Orientation</th>
        <th>Parallelism</th>
    </tr>
</thead><thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th><select id='filter.productionarea'></select></th>
        <th><select id='filter.format'></select></th>
        <th><select id='filter.orientation'></select></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

and that's JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var table = $( '#probecardlist' ).dataTable({
    'ajax' : 'http://whaelse.url/query.php',
    'paging' : false,
    'searching' : false,
    'ordering' : true,
    'columns' : [
        { 'data' : 'selection' },
        { 'data' : 'id' },
        { 'data' : 'productionarea' },
        { 'data' : 'format' },
        { 'data' : 'orientation' },
        { 'data' : 'dicecount' }
    ],
    'fnInitComplete' : function( oSettings , json ) {
        console.log( this.column( 'format:name' ).data() );
             })
})
});
```

When I try just to list (on consolle) the list of values of column "format" I get such error:

Object #HTMLTableElement has no method 'column'.

Mhm... What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The 'fnInitComplete' implements the [ this.api() ] method to get the property of the object

```
'fnInitComplete' : function ( oSettings , json ) {
     var api = this.api();
     api.column ( 'format:name' ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( v ) {
        console.log (v);
     });
  }
```